# Ethereum Solo Mining - Adding additional miners to the rig

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I am new to mining and have setup my test mining setup in EC2. I know that this is not profitable but doing to understand how this works.

I have 2 EC2 instances where in the first instance, I am running geth which syncs block chain. Also, in the same instance I am using ethminer and doing GPU based mining. In this instance, I have created a geth account.

In the second EC2 instance, I am only running ethminer and is connected to the first EC2 instance's geth farm. I can see both the miners doing at around 36 MH/s.

My question is - Am I doing this correctly? Also, is it required for me to setup an account in the second ec2 instance? Currently, I have not added any account in that instance. I am assuming that both the miners are contributing the account that I defined in my first Ec2 instance. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Thank you.